# What calls the Start() method in NuGet Packages (ex:AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

I've installed the AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery NuGet package.  The dll contains code to register jQuery as a bundle.  My questions is what calls this code?  What calls the Start() method?  Many NuGet packages automatically do stuff without you ever having to write code so somehow they are getting called.  How does it work?

```
namespace AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static class PreApplicationStartCode
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class and method are specified in the assembly.

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]

This is processed after the assembly is loaded.